# Deleting existing data and thereafter appending updated data to hosted feature layer (layer within group layer) in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, update, delete, append, hosted-feature-layer

I am trying to figure out how to append new data to an existing feature layer in ArcGIS Online. I have tried to solely append the data (in ArcGIS Online), but the problem arises when I receive duplicated data in the attribute table from this action. What I want to do is to remove all original data in the feature layer and thereafter add the new data with its expanded geometrical properties.

Does anyone have any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this manually through the web interface, or to automate it, or from ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Take a look at the [python api](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html?highlight=append#arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.append) for infomation about using the `append` command. Note in particular the section regarding the **upsert** parameter: **Optional parameter specifying whether the edits needs to be applied as updates if the feature already exists. Default is false.**